# Reading Python/Command Prompt line output C#

Tags: c#, python, batch-file

I am trying to make a log using a C# windows form application. The goal here is to press a button to start a batch file (below) and get the text/data written to the command prompt, as it is written if possible, then send it to a listbox on my application. Think of it as a program for a server (which its not, its a discord bot.), my goal is just to have the "logs" sent to the application in real time.

Question: How can I create my own console inside my windows form application, example would be: If an echo said "Hello" I want it to display "Hello" in my listbox in realtime.

CMD File being Ran

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Users\gunzb\Desktop\Tarkov Bot\"
:loop
py bot.py
SET /A time=3
:timer
timeout /t 1 /nobreak>nul
echo Restarting in %time%
SET /A time-=1
IF %time% EQU 0 (goto skiploop) ELSE (goto timer)
:skiploop
goto loop
```

I have no idea where to start as when I search for this topic I get other languages or other methods that dont seem to either do it in real time or doesnt work at all. Thank you for any help given.

EDIT: The python script makes the `writelines` but I believe these can also be taken from the CMD process itself, not sure though.

EDIT:

```
        public void StartBotBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process proc = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo si = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            proc.OutputDataReceived += ProcessOutputHandler;
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Users\\gunzb\\Desktop\\Tarkov Bot\\start.bat";
            proc.Start();
            proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
            proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
            processid = proc.Id;
        }
        private void StopBotBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Array.ForEach(Process.GetProcessesByName("py"), x => x.Kill());
            Array.ForEach(Process.GetProcessesByName("cmd"), x => x.Kill());
        }
        private void ProcessOutputHandler(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.listBox1.Items.Add(e.Data); //This is where I get confused.
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's the question. Is it partially working? Are you getting any error?

Comment: @JuanCristóbalOlivares Updated with a section stating "Question" for more clairification.

Comment: Please make sure that you change the name of your variable in the batch file, to something which isn't an important system variable.

Comment: Lol, yes I'll correct that @Compo

Comment: You don't need the batch file.  You can execute the python script directly from your C# code.  Just start a thread on StartBotBtn_Click that loops over your Process code.